# Updating progress bar string with "\r" at the start, skips or misses the iterations

Tags: c, linux, bash, terminal

I want to write a simple progress bar function in C for further use, but occurred with a problem. While updating the progress bar string by "\r" and printing its new value, function misses or skips iterations.

I've made [a video](https://youtu.be/svYbPxN8E_w) where you can see that function is properly calculating and building the string for each iteration, but when i add "\r" at the start of the string it starts to skip iterations.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void render_progress_bar( int, int, int, char, char );

int main( void ) {
    for ( int i = 1; i <= 60; i++ ) {
            render_progress_bar( i, 60, 50, '#', ' ' );
            usleep( 64000 );
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void render_progress_bar( int current_iteration,
                          int total_iterations,
                          int length_of_bar,
                          char filled_bar_char,
                          char non_filled_bar_char ) {
    // Calculating amount of percents reached at current iteration
    double percents = (double) current_iteration / total_iterations * 100;
    // Calculating amount of chars to fill in progress bar string
    int amount_to_fill = length_of_bar * current_iteration / total_iterations; 

    // Prepaering bar string
    char * bar_string = malloc( length_of_bar + 2 );
    bar_string[ 0 ] = '['; bar_string[ length_of_bar + 1 ] = ']';
    memset( bar_string + 1, filled_bar_char, amount_to_fill );
    memset( bar_string + amount_to_fill + 1, non_filled_bar_char, length_of_bar - amount_to_fill );

    // Printing the rendered progress string
    printf( "Progress: %s %02.1lf Completed...\n", bar_string, percents );

    // If reached 100% print new line
    if ( current_iteration == total_iterations ) printf( "\n" );
}
```

The result i want to get is shown in this [video](https://youtu.be/6-P5MIV1hOI). The python code which does exactly the same thing, but correctly:

```
from time import sleep

print( '[*] Starting ...' )
sleep( 1 )

for i in range( 1, 61 ) :
    # Calculating completed percents and length of bar to fill as completed
    percents    = '%.2f' % ( i / 60 * 100 )
    filled_area = int( 50 * i / 60 )

    # Preparing progress bar string
    bar_string  = ( '█' * filled_area ) + ( ' ' * ( 50 - filled_area ) )

    # Printing progress bar with some info and EOL if reached 100%
    print( '\rProgress: [%s] %s%% Completed ...\r' % ( bar_string, percents ), end = '' )
    if i == 60 : print( )

    sleep( 0.1 )
```

Comment: At the very least you are not properly terminating the string (or reserving enough space to include the terminating NUL byte).

Comment: That looks like block buffering. Try `fflush(stdout);` after each `printf`.

Comment: 1) fix the missing termination and insufficient length of `bar_string`, 2) add `fflush(stdout)` after `printf`, 3) change the `\n` to `\r`, 4) print at least one line ending in a `\n` before the first progress is printed

Comment: regarding: `double percents = (double) current_iteration / total_iterations * 100;`  strongly suggest changing `100` to `100.0` so the calculations are all done in `double` rather than some of the calculations being done in `integer` as an `integer` divide drops all the fractional part

Comment: regarding: `char * bar_string = malloc( length_of_bar + 2 );`  just allocate  the max length of the bar, one time, suggest using a static allocation rather than a dynamic allocation.  Also, the posted code has a massive memory leak from all to calls to `malloc()` an never passing the resulting memory pointer to `free()`.  Aldo, when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `mallco` `realloc` `calloc`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: regarding: `[char * bar_string = malloc( length_of_bar + 2 );`  the modulo operator only works with integer values, not with fractions.  Suggest you use: `fmod()` from the `math.h` header file

Comment: what are you expecting: `bar_string  = ( '█' * filled_area ) + ( ' ' * ( 50 - filled_area )` to do?  and what is that strange character between the first two ' ' characters?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any missed iterations.

However, I do see where the percentage calculations are being done in integer math (which always rounds) rather than in `double` math